# How to log contents of HTML5 drag and drop file that is 60MB+ without hanging for minutes?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a file that i want to drop on a page and read file contents. its a CSV with 9 columns. My drop command outputs file contents like this:

```
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data  = ev.dataTransfer.files[0];

    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function (e) {
        console.log(fileReader.result)
    };
    fileReader.onerror = function (e) {
        throw 'Error reading CSV file';
    };

    // Start reading file
    fileReader.readAsText(data);

    return false;    
}
```

When I drag and drop a simple file that is a couple kilobytes or 1MB, I can see the output of the contents of the file. However given a large CSV file, it takes many many minutes before it shows up. Is there a way to make it so that there is some streaming maybe where it does not look like its hanging?

Answer (score 0):

With [Screw-FileReader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/screw-filereader)
You can get a ReadableStream and do it in a streaming fashion

```js
'use strict'

var blob = new Blob(['111,222,333\naaa,bbb,ccc']) // simulate a file
var stream = blob.stream()
var reader = stream.getReader()
var headerString = ''
var forEachLine = function(row) {
  var colums = row.split(',')
    // append to DOM
  console.log(colums)
}

var pump = function() {
  return reader.read().then(function(result) {
    var value = result.value
    var done = result.done

    if (done) {
      // Do the last line
      headerString && forEachLine(headerString)
      return
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
      // Get the character for the current iteration
      var char = String.fromCharCode(value[i])

      // Check if the char is a new line
      if (char.match(/[^\r\n]+/g) !== null) {
        // Not a new line so lets append it to
        // our header string and keep processing
        headerString += char
      } else {
        // We found a new line character
        forEachLine(headerString)
        headerString = ''
      }
    }

    return pump()
  })
}

pump().then(function() {
  console.log('done reading the csv')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jimmywarting/Screw-FileReader/master/index.js"></script>
```

If you prefer using the old FileReader without dependencies, pipe's and transform

```js
'use strict'

var blob = new Blob(['111,222,333\naaa,bbb,ccc']) // simulate a file
var fr = new FileReader()
var headerString = ''
var position = 0
var forEachLine = function forEachLine(row) {
  var colums = row.split(',')
    // append to DOM
  console.log(colums)
}

var pump = function pump() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    var chunk = blob.slice(position, position + 524288)
    position += 524288
    fr.onload = function() {
      var value = fr.result
      var done = position >= blob.size

      for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        var char = value[i]

        // Check if the char is a new line
        if (char.match(/[^\r\n]+/g) !== null) {
          // Not a new line so lets append it to
          // our header string and keep processing
          headerString += char
        } else {
          // We found a new line character
          forEachLine(headerString)
          headerString = ''
        }
      }

      if (done) {
        // Send the last line
        forEachLine(headerString)
        return resolve() // done
      }

      return resolve(pump())
    }

    // Read the next chunk
    fr.readAsText(chunk)
  })
}

pump().then(function() {
  console.log('done reading the csv')
})
```

Comment: any vanilla javascript sample of this?

Comment: It's vanilla javascript, just so happens to be written in ES6. Or are you asking if it can be done without any dependencies?

Comment: Asking about how it would look in ES5.

Comment: Added a snippet that use the FileReader

Comment: give me a secound and i will rewrite it in es5

Comment: There you have it both method are now in es5

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is `524288`?

Comment: @strah 2^19 ≈ 0.5 MB chunks

Comment: Or exactly 0.5 MiB

Comment: I ported node's [byLine](https://github.com/jahewson/node-byline) to use web streams and now this is what i came up with: https://jsfiddle.net/gp802r79/